# Livecode (Run Rev) Admob for implementation for Android

Tags: android, admob, livecode

I understand that Livecode officially doesn't support Admob (only support inneractive ads). But, I really would like to know if there is any expert have any workaround (e.g. modifying the default AndroidManifest.xml template? inject the admob jar? develop a plug-in for admob?).

Really appreciate if there is any hints and guidance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Standalone Builder to adjust the AndroidManifext.xml template before it is included in the standalone package. However, it looks like the changes in the manifext are mainly required to allow for internet access and to indicate that your app needs to run on Android 2.3 or later. You can already do this in the Standalone Application Settings window and you don't need to make additional adjustments.

You can [create an ad view in pure XML](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play-xml). This means that such an ad view can be included in a web site, which can be displayed in a revBrowser control. Everything else on the Android tutorial pages is just meant to display the ad and you can ignore it if you're developing with LiveCode.

Probably, when using XML, you have to replace @+id/adView with some ID number for testing. I don't know what you need to put here. Maybe you should ask an experienced Android developer about this on an Android forum or hopefully someone with more Android experience will provide a better answer.

On a side note, it should also be possible to create an external for iOS. If you create an external, you could take advantage of the complete AdMob API.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your direction and reply. BTW, there is a admob jar library, how could I put it in the livecode project? Thanks in advance. Cheers